# Remove excess of pipes '|' in CSV after append files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have 3 dataframes. I need to convert them in one merged CSV separated by pipes '|'.

And I need to sort them by Column1 after append.

But, when I try to convert the final df to CSV, there comes exceeded pipes for null columns. How to avoid this?

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column1': ['key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3'],
    'Column2': ['1100', '1100', '1100']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column1': ['key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3', 'key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3'],
    'Column2': ['1110', '1110', '1110', '1110', '1110', '1110'],
    'Column3': ['xxr', 'xxv', 'xxw', 'xxt', 'xxe', 'xxz'],
    'Column4': ['wer', 'cad', 'sder', 'dse', 'sdf', 'csd']
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column1': ['key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3', 'key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3'],
    'Column2': ['1115', '1115', '1115', '1115', '1115', '1115'],
    'Column3': ['xxr', 'xxv', 'xxw', 'xxt', 'xxe', 'xxz'],
    'Column4': ['wer', 'cad', 'sder', 'dse', 'sdf', 'csd'],
    'Column5': ['xxr', 'xxv', 'xxw', 'xxt', 'xxe', 'xxz'],
    'Column6': ['xxr', 'xxv', 'xxw', 'xxt', 'xxe', 'xxz'],
})

print(df1, df2, df3, sep="\n")

output = io.StringIO()

pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).sort_values("Column1") \
  .to_csv(output, header=False, index=False, sep="|")

print("csv",output.getvalue(),sep="\n")

output.seek(0)

df4 = pd.read_csv(output, header=None, sep="|", keep_default_na=False)

print("df4",df4,sep="\n" )

output.close()
```

***This is the output I have (note pipes'|'):***

```
key_1|1100||||
key_1|1110|xxr|wer||
key_1|1110|xxt|dse||
key_1|1115|xxr|wer|xxr|xxr
key_1|1115|xxt|dse|xxt|xxt
key_2|1100||||
key_2|1110|xxv|cad||
key_2|1110|xxe|sdf||
key_2|1115|xxv|cad|xxv|xxv
key_2|1115|xxe|sdf|xxe|xxe
key_3|1100||||
key_3|1110|xxw|sder||
key_3|1110|xxz|csd||
key_3|1115|xxw|sder|xxw|xxw
key_3|1115|xxz|csd|xxz|xxz
```

***I need this. Justo to introduce, I'll not work on this final data, I need to upload it to a specific database in the exact format I show below, but I need this without using regex (note pipes'|'). Is there a way to do so?***

```
key_1|1100
key_1|1110|xxr|wer
key_1|1110|xxt|dse
key_1|1115|xxr|wer|xxr|xxr
key_1|1115|xxt|dse|xxt|xxt
key_2|1100
key_2|1110|xxv|cad
key_2|1110|xxe|sdf
key_2|1115|xxv|cad|xxv|xxv
key_2|1115|xxe|sdf|xxe|xxe
key_3|1100
key_3|1110|xxw|sder
key_3|1110|xxz|csd
key_3|1115|xxw|sder|xxw|xxw
key_3|1115|xxz|csd|xxz|xxz
```

Comment: what you're asking for is not valid CSV, the reason you have empty pipes is expected because those columns don't exist in every row, hence the empty values between pipes, also what database is even accepting an uneven number of columns? doesn't make much sense

Comment: It's not valid CSV, but if that's what you need, then you can iterate over the lines and use [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to remove the pipes.

Comment: yes, I thought of the rstrip solution. but it won't work for me. thanks

Comment: Why `rstrip` doesn't work?. It raises an exception?

Comment: Just because those tables will probably change columns over time and I'm not sure regex solutions will be flexible enough for this. I'll probably loop through each line in each table in the right sort order and append always in the right format. thanks for the help, elucidated me some ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- as you note, generate sorted pipe delimited
- then `split()`, `rstrip("|")` and `join()`

```
"\n".join([l.rstrip("|") for l in 
           pd.concat([df1,df2,df3]).pipe(lambda d: 
                                         d.sort_values(d.columns.tolist())).to_csv(sep="|", index=False).split("\n")])
```

Comment: Thank you. As I said, I can't do this with regex for several reasons. But I'll work on it. Best Regards.

Comment: there is no reg expression used in this solution.  I took note of that

Comment: isn't rstrip a type of regex? Just because those tables will probably change columns over time and I'm not sure regex solutions will be flexible enough for this. I'll probably loop through each line in each table in the right sort order and append always in the right format. thanks for the help, elucidated me some ideas

Comment: `rstrip()` is right strip,  not reg expression.  effectively removes padding on end of line

Comment: sorry my friend. wrote wrong. 'string' functions won't work. already figure out another harder solution. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can remove extra "|" with `re.sub()`:

```
import re

s = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).sort_values("Column1") \
      .to_csv(header=False, index=False, sep="|")

s1 = re.sub("\|*\n", "\n", s)  # with regex

s2 = "\n".join([l.rstrip("|") for l in s.splitlines()])  # with rstrip
```

```
>>> print(s1.strip())
key_1|1100
key_1|1110|xxr|wer
key_1|1110|xxt|dse
key_1|1115|xxr|wer|xxr|xxr
key_1|1115|xxt|dse|xxt|xxt
key_2|1100
key_2|1110|xxv|cad
key_2|1110|xxe|sdf
key_2|1115|xxv|cad|xxv|xxv
key_2|1115|xxe|sdf|xxe|xxe
key_3|1100
key_3|1110|xxw|sder
key_3|1110|xxz|csd
key_3|1115|xxw|sder|xxw|xxw
key_3|1115|xxz|csd|xxz|xxz

>>> print(s2)
key_1|1100
key_1|1110|xxr|wer
key_1|1110|xxt|dse
key_1|1115|xxr|wer|xxr|xxr
key_1|1115|xxt|dse|xxt|xxt
key_2|1100
key_2|1110|xxv|cad
key_2|1110|xxe|sdf
key_2|1115|xxv|cad|xxv|xxv
key_2|1115|xxe|sdf|xxe|xxe
key_3|1100
key_3|1110|xxw|sder
key_3|1110|xxz|csd
key_3|1115|xxw|sder|xxw|xxw
key_3|1115|xxz|csd|xxz|xxz
```

Comment: Thank you. As I said, I can't do this with regex for several reasons. But I'll work on it. Best Regards.